# Encoding Problems with dropbox on fat32 used on Windows and Debian

Tags: windows-8, debian, dropbox, encoding

I am using an encrypted (Truecrypt) data-Partition (fat32), on which my Dropbox folder is located. This Partition is mounted on Windows 8 as well as Crunchbang (Debian wheezy) and Ubuntu 12.10. When it has mounted, Dropbox starts to synchronize the folder (in principle on every OS, **but currently only Crunchbang is configured for Dropbox**).

Now when I save a file or create a directory with a special character (umlauts in particular), then this file/folder will be renamed - three times, creating three items with the same content, but different names.

An example:

- bafög.odt
- bafÃ¶g.odt
- bafÃÂ¶g.odt

This only happens inside the Dropbox directory, every other directory works fine. Since I am german, it is impractical to avoid special characters (especially umlauts), most of all winside shared dropbox folders, because then I'd have to ask everyone to avoid those characters too.

Comment: Why don't you just avoid these characters?  The encoding problem can easily explained on the Windows machine.  As for the two Linux installations I assume your using the same region and language for those?

Comment: Since I am german, it is impractical to avoid umlauts - most of all, sicne I have shared folders inside Dropbox I'd have to convince the other people using the folders to avoid those characters as well. As I said, currently only Crunchbang is configured to use Dropbox so I suspect that my Filesystem encodes differently than Dropbox transmits. Also, deleting the files with faulty names leaves one perfectly good file on Dropbox and my Computer.

Comment: That is important information update your question to reflect that information.